# GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) push notification from python app server to iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to send push notifications to my iOS app with GCM. I tried to follow the ([Google GCM](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/ios/gcm/GcmExample)) and ([GCMServerDemo](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/ios/gcm/GcmServerDemo)) for my app but I only can receive the notification printed on the xcode output: `[body: hello, it's me, sound: default, collapse_key: do_not_collapse, badge: 2, from: 629354528047]` but nothing pop out on my testing phone. My server running on python and I have it implemented as:

```
from gcm import *

gcm= GCM("123...")
DEV_TOKEN = "l0NOTncXJXQ:APA91bGPVHxvF-PCL-PPNic6zhfnpv0aAe5KhvoYOOF_HfLZlCAquMGQb196J5_4zUEzWEirSOWP86d-n4-DJws4nPs5ZXR1c9UOQOPPuuCAjXFz2VIZ-5_SRz8G6D_MzKHv1W7yRrmZ"
reg_ids = [DEV_TOKEN]
notification = {"body": "hello, it's me", "sound": "default", "badge": 2}
response=gcm.json_request(registration_ids=reg_ids, data=notification)
print(response)
```

My AppDelegate on my app client to detect notification: http://swiftstub.com/621889661/

My ViewController: http://swiftstub.com/89730359

I want my client app receive the notification both when the app is active and when the screen is off (but right now I only can receive the message sent on my server in the xcode output screen, as `[body: hello, it's me, sound: default, collapse_key: do_not_collapse, badge: 2, from: 629354528047]`)
I guess there is a problem when I parse the received message. Can anyone help me to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: I you only want to display a message you don't need "content-available" = 1

Comment: what library are you using in python?

Comment: This is the whole code I used on my server, http://codepaste.net/khxm5x .I did the similar thing and was able to my android phone, but when I tried to send it to my iphone, I couldn't receid the notification (only the message printed on the output)

Comment: It looks like you're defining the `notification` variable, but you're not using it when calling `gm.json-request`. This line: `response=gcm.json_request(registration_ids=reg_ids, data=test1)` should be `response=gcm.json_request(registration_ids=reg_ids, notification=notification)`

Comment: it was my typo, I write a couple payload to test, and I tried the notification but it also show nothing on my phone :(

Comment: I see you edited the answer, but it's still wrong. Please look carefully at my previous reply.

Comment: Oh my bad, I fixed the json_request function, but it's weird that it does show notification when I turned off the screen, but when the app is active, it does not. I guess we are so close. Do you have any other idea? Thank you...

Comment: Notifications are not shown when the app is active. You get them in the AppDelegate and you need to display them yourself if you think it's necessary in your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the gcm payload should look like if all you want to do is display a message to the user:

```
{
  "to":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
  "notification":{
    "body":"This text message will be seen by the user",
    "badge": 2,
    "sound": "default"
  }
}
```

It will only be visible by default when the app is not in the foreground. When it is, you need to read the message in your `AppDelegate`'s `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method, and show it to the user yourself.

Edit:

Instead of using `gcm.plaintext_request(registration_id=reg_id,data = data)`
 you might want to try this:

```
notification = {'body': "hello, it's me", "sound": "default", "badge": 2}
DEV_TOKEN = '**********************************'
reg_ids = [DEV_TOKEN]
response = gcm.json_request(registration_ids=reg_ids, notification=notification)
```

`notification` should be outside the data key

Comment: I change my sending message format as you suggested and what I received was "Notification received: [collapse_key: do_not_collapse, to: my_registration_token, notification: body, from: 629354528047]", while I tried it on the GCMDemo server written in swift, I can receive and read the message on my client app, even when I lock the screen.

Comment: I'm very appreciate your great help marosoaie, but I tried and it does not work. My current code is http://codepaste.net/4vowis, but it got an error "GCMMissingRegistrationException("Missing registration_ids")
gcm.gcm.GCMMissingRegistrationException: Missing registration_ids" Although there is a registration_ids in the argument list? and the registration token is valid. Agrrrr, I'm so confused :(

Comment: @shjnlee I edited the answer again. I think you just need to replace `registration_id` with `registration_ids` which is an array.

Comment: That was a silly mistake of mine. Still, I couldn't received any notification :(. When I tried to print the response after calling the gcm.json_request(), I received this: {'errors': defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {u'InvalidRegistration': ['l0NOTncXJXQ:APA91bGPVHxvF-PCL-PPNic6zhfnpv0aAe5KhvoYOOF_HfLZlCiAquMGQb196J5_4zUEzWEirSOWP86d-n4-DJws4nPs5ZXR1c9UOQOPPuuCAjXFz2VIZ-5_SRz8G6D_MzKHv1W7yRrmZ']})} My current server code is: http://codepaste.net/xyih3v

Comment: It might be possible that the token for the device you are testing was refreshed and is not valid anymore. You should check that the registration token of your device is actually the one you used in your python code. Assuming that you are using the GCM AppDelegate template from Google in your iOS app, you can check the token by logging the `registrationToken` property in your code when it's set.

Comment: Thank you so much marosoaie. I wish I could mark your answer as accepted, but my notification won't show up. Yes, I received the printed output on the xcode as [body: hello, it's me, sound: default, collapse_key: do_not_collapse, badge: 2, from: 629354528047] but I still cannot received it on my testing phone (while if I used the GCM Demo server, I could receive it) Is there any problem that my app might have to prevent showing the notification?

Comment: Ha, that's weird. Can you post a copy of your current server code once more?

Comment: Hi marosoaie, I just edited the question for everyone can follow it. Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it.